# How to integrate javascript rendering module to scrapy?

Tags: javascript, python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am working on a web scraping program, but I have run into a problem using scrapy with javascript generated content. I know that scrapy is not built to do this type of scraping, but I have been trying to use [scrapyjs](https://github.com/scrapinghub/scrapyjs) or [splash](https://github.com/scrapinghub/splash) to accomplish what I need.

However, I cannot get either of these two modules to work correctly with scrapy. My question is if anyone has a minimal example they can show that uses scrapyjs or splash to render javascript pages?

Edit:
My platform is ubuntu and I working with python. For scrapyjs I just put the source in the uppermost directory of the scrapy project and I have yet to find any real guides on how to use splash. The reason I am asking about splash is because it seems a more powerful module for javascript rendering and is mentioned a lot in the same conversation as scrapjs.

Comment: What's your platform, how did you install scrapyjs or splash? What errors if any are you getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe all you have to do is implement [process_links in your Spider](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html):

```
def proxy_url(url):
        return "http://localhost:8050/render.html?url=%s&timeout=15&wait=1" % url


def process_links(self,links):
        for link in links:
            link.url = proxy_url(link.url)
        return links
```

Comment: I don't fully understand what proxy_url() is doing. Could you explain?

Comment: I got your solution to work in a slightly modified form.

Comment: @Adamkucera, Can you please share the modified form?

Comment: @MahmoudM.Abdel-Fattah What I did was put the splash mechanism to generate js inside a parse function only if the response requires it. I didn't put it in front of all of the links if I don't need to. Does this help?

Comment: Can you update your answer and show us a sample. I don't use Python on a daily basis and would like to see your sample code please.